# How to make an infinite loop on array with ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I'm coding a simple angular 4 game, a quiz where players have to answer one by one. I have a simple array like this :

```
this.listPLayers = [{name:'Toto', score:0}, {name:'Tutu',score:0},{name:"Titi',score:O}];
```

When player answer, I handle this function :

```
 getAnswer(answer, player){
      this.nbOfQuestions = this.nbOfQuestions - 1;
      this.listPlayers.splice(0,1);

        if(answer.isTrue == true) {
            player.score = player.score + 1;
            this.showModal(right);
        } else {
            this.showModal(bad);
        }
}
```

And HTML :

```
<span class="player" *ngFor="let player of listPlayers.slice(0, 1)">{{player.name}} : </span>
```

The goal is to make an infinite loop on listPlayers, but without lose the score.

EDIT :
On HTMl I just take the first index of the array to display it. Every time a player answer to a question, I splice the array to display the next player.
To make it simple the ngFor should display (one bye one):

Toto, Tutu, Titi, Toto, Tutu, Titi, Toto, Tutu, Titi, ....

Comment: What do you mean with infinite loop, do you mean that it goes through the whole listplayers array?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to make an infinite loop? Are you sure that you don't just want to update an event handler callback function for each answer? I.E. you could have a question, then in the callback, you could have a new question rendered to the same HTML, and a new callback function. The event handler will simulate an endless loop, as the event handler will never go unless you command it to do so.

Comment: WillemvanderVeen :  I edit my question to make it clear.
JO3-W3B-D3V :  I'm not sur to see what you mean..

Comment: Let me get this straight: you want to display the name of the player whose turn it is now and a question for the player to answer. When they answer, you want to update their score and display a dialog saying if they were right or not. Then you want to update the view with the name of the player whose turn it is next and the question for them to answer. Correct?

Comment: Yes that's it !

Comment: In that case, ngFor and infinite loop is not the right approach. Maintain a variable, say, `currPlayer`. Initialize it with the first player in `listPLayers`. Then in the `getAnswer`, update it with the next player in `listPLayers`. Use `currPlayer.name` in your view to display the player name.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll try it !

Answer (score 0):

We don't code long running processes in the browser the way we do with platform code. So your thought of an infinite loop makes sense in the context of a server process for instance.

On the client we use the eventing system to accomplish the same goal.

1. Set up an action to occur upon some stimulus

   - run getAnswer when question answered
2. Set stimulus (question answered) to notify of stimulus

   - emit event notifying that question has been answered

[AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) provides `$broadcast` and `$emit` 
and Angular provides the [EventEmitter Class](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) for these purposes.

The docs for [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) have a good example of how to accomplish this with Angular.